# Android Tab Layout error

Tags: android, layout, tabs

Newbie here...

I'm trying to both learn and get The Tab Layout working (as seen [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)) but have come across a few errors. All have been resolved except the following:

[ArtistsActivity cannot be resolved to a type.]

I get it for the following:

```
ArtistsActivity.class
AlbumsActivity.class
SongsActivity.class
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks for any and all help.

(Going to register for a Java Class this Fall Semester.)

**HelloTabWidget.java**

```
package com.HelloTabWidget.tabs;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;



public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this for calling intent place

```
    Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ArtistsActivity.class);
    startActivity(showContent);
```